# How to view only the unmerged files in git after a merge failure

Tags: git

While merging some of the files failed to merge.

```
git status
```

shows both the successful and failed merges.

How to view only the unsuccessful merge files(conflict).

Currently i am using the following command to do this

```
 find . -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.h' | xargs grep -l '<<<<'
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
git diff
```

This will only show failed merges after an unsuccessful merge. It has many options to configure what information you want to see. I suspect this is the exact option you are after:

```
 git diff --name-status --diff-filter=U
```

Also see http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#resolving-a-merge and http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html

Comment: If you want a clean list of files without the preceding U, then you can call `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U`. This way you can pipe the output, for example do `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | xargs subl`.

Answer (score 13):

```
git --no-pager diff --name-only --diff-filter=U
```

But since the goal is most likely to edit those files, the following will do perfectly:

```
vim $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U)
```

Or in Windows with VS Code:

```
foreach($file in $(git --no-pager diff --name-only --diff-filter=U)){code.cmd $file --wait}
```

Thanks to @JHannes comment from another answer for inspiration

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
$ git ls-files -u
see man-git-ls-files
```

Comment: I like this command, because it will not display the status code before each file name. Since we already specify with the use of the filter we only want the unmerged files, this status code is of no use anymore and can be omitted. However, the same can be achieved via `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U`.